# Trace of logarithm of kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I want to see how 
$$\text{trace} [\log (A^{\otimes n})]$$
scales with $n$, where $A$ is a $d\times d$ positive definite matrix and
$$A^{\otimes n}=\underbrace{A\otimes A \otimes \cdots \otimes A}_{n\; \text{times}} $$
My feeling is that $\text{trace} [\log (A^{\otimes n})]$ should scale polynomial in $n$ because of the logarithm, but if I write it in terms of eigenvalues  of $\log (A^{\otimes n})$, since $\log (A^{\otimes n})$ is a $d^n\times d^n$ matrix, we will have $d^n$ terms, i.e. 
$$\text{trace} [\log (A^{\otimes n})]=\sum_{i=1}^{d^n}\lambda_i$$
$\lambda_i$s are eigenvalues of $\log (A^{\otimes n})$. Thus, it scales exponential in $n$.

Am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\text{trace}\,(\log(A^{\otimes n}))=\log(\det(A^{\otimes n}))=\log((\det A)^n)=n\log\det A=n\,\text{trace}\,(\log A). 
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to show it using eigenvalues? I still cannot understand what is my mistake when I am trying to compute the trace using eigenvalues?

Comment: If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, the eigenvalues of $A^{\otimes n}$ are $$\{\lambda_{k_1}\cdots\lambda_{k_n}:\  k_1,\ldots,k_n=1,\ldots,m\}.$$

So 
\begin{align}
\text{tr}\,(\log A^{\otimes n})&=\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n=1}^m\log(\lambda_{k_1}\cdots\lambda_{k_n})
=\log\left(\prod_{k_1,\ldots,k_n=1}^m\lambda_{k_1}\cdots\lambda_{k_n}\right)\\ \ \\
&=\log\left(\left[\prod_{k=1}^m\lambda_k\right]^n\right)
=n\,\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^m\lambda_k\right)
=n\,\log(\det A)
\end{align}